# What is the best way to gather salesforce data on org limit / static resource usage using REST or SFDX CLI

Tags: rest-api, salesforcedx, metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli, static-resources

I want to keep track of our SF org portfolio/governor limit usage over time and am looking for a way to gather that data in real time. Is there a way to gather info on limit usage such as:

- Lookups on a field / object
- Number of static resources and the totality of their size

amongst other data points of SF org limits

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked this - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMiIfUAL 

Its from Salesforce Labs.

Comment: @YsrShk Thanks for the link, I'll check it out!

Comment: @YsrShk consider posting an answer :)

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_limits.htm or `OrgLimits` in Apex. The latter option is used by SF Labs app.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the App Exchange package developed by Salesforce Labs.

Link - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMiIfUAL

Open Source Link - https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/LimitsMonitor

It can show limits in the dashboard like below and has custom alerting capabilities -
[image: Org Limits Dashboard]

[image: Dashboard with tabular details]

[image: Custom Alerting facilities]